# How to set up what volume is displayed in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to display a particular volume of space, the cube from 10,10,10 to 30,30,30. From everything I read, I'd do this like so:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f,
    20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  //color = black
glPushMatrix();               
    glTranslated(20,20,20);
    glutSolidSphere(.3, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();
```

`glOrtho` sets up what volume I can see, and `gluLookAt` says that the camera is at 30,30,30 and is pointed at 20,20,20. But this doesn't work. With some help and some playing around, I managed to get this working, with this code:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(10, 30, 10, 30, -1000, 1000);  //CHANGED THESE BOUNDS

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslated(20,20,20);                //ADDED THIS LINE 
gluLookAt(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f,
    20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


glPushMatrix();               
    glTranslated(20,20,20);
    glutSolidSphere(.3, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();
```

Why do I need those changes? Why doesn't the first version of the code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30);
```

will set up a matrix which will transform the cuboid x=[10,30], y=[10,30] and z=[ -10, -30] to the [-1,1]^3 clip space volume (which is OpenGL's viewing volume). Note the negative sign here.

This code

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f,
    20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

set up a translation of all objects of (-30,. -30, -30) and some rotation to look into the direction you specified.

*Both* matrices will be applied, first the `ModelView` to get into eye space, than the `Projection` matrix to get into clip space. So now, if you want to think in terms of a global "world space", you end up with a viewing volume which is the 20 units wide, high and deep, but lies somewhere you don't really expect it. It will begin 10 units *behind* at what you set as the view direction axis. and also be shifted along the camera's local x and y axis - the point you specified your camera to look at will not even end up on the screen.

If you just wanted the [10,30]^3 viewing volume, you could simply use

```
glOrtho(10, 30, 10, 30, -10, -30);
```

and *remove that `gluLookAt()` alltogether*. This will at least work for simple cases, but it might screw up lighting and fog, since the "camera" is now at original. You probably want to set up some symmetric viewing volume, so that you actually can have any sane camera setup.

**EDIT**

To make things more clear: the viewing volume you define in the projection matrix is defined *relative* to the view transformation in that setup. So, you might for examle want to a viewing volume of size 20x20x20, where your viewing axis lies in the center of the porjection, and showung the volume which lies directly in front of the camera:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, 0, 20);
```

Now you can set up your camera location as before:
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f,
        20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Now, the point (20,20,20) (where you draw your sphere) will actually be projected to the center of the screen. However, it will be not at the center of the viewing voulme, since it wall range from 0 to 20 units along the current viewing axis, but (20,20,20) is 17.32 units away from the current camera position of (30,30,30). So you could set the camera to
    gluLookAt(25.774f, 25.774f, 25.774f,
        20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Now, the object is exaclty in the center of the viewing volume.

Comment: Ok, so after `glOrtho()` the [10,30]^3 is mapped to [-1,1]^3, and the camera is located at 0,0,0, right? Without `gluLookAt()` I see things in 2d, with the x-axis horizontal and y vertical. I wanted to see things from an angle, so I can see along all 3 axes, but if I try to put the camera at the corner and look at the center, it still doesn't work: `gluLookAt(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);` I think I'm still misunderstanding this scenario...

Comment: @drowdemon: Yeah, you do. You now seems to confuse the viewing volume after projection woth the one before. View transform is typically applied _before_ the projection. I updated my answer.