# GL_POINTS drawing only one point instead of many

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this code which is supposed to draw a number of points on screen :

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
           glVertex3f(array1[i][j], array2[i][j], array3[i][j]); 
           cout<<array1[i][j]<<" "<<array2[i][j]<<" "<<array3[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }

glEnd();
```

I only get one point on the screen. I can't imagine how this is happening. I am printing array values, they are all different, but I am getting only one point instead of a few hundred points. Can you tell what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Which range do your points have along x and y? Could it be that only one of your points is in the visible range?

Comment: @BDL they range between 25 and 0. Thanks.

Comment: When you do not use any projections, the visible range is from -1 to 1. You can change that for example by using glOrtho

Comment: @BDL using gluPerspective solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that either only one point out of your dataset falls in the viewport, or that all the points end up being projected to only one visible pixel. Either way you should check your projection range. You could extract the bounding box of your dataset and [set the viewing volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140559/how-to-set-up-what-volume-is-displayed-in-opengl) to be slightly larger than that.